# Laravel vendor:publish adds random text to the published files

Tags: laravel, package, vendor

I'm building a package and I'm publishing a folder with CSS and JavaScript files to the host project. Using the following code

```
$this->publishes([__DIR__ . '/../../public' => public_path('vendor/cld')], 'ui');
```

The paths are all checked and correct. It's publishing the requested files but with random (not so random) text in front of it.

For example my **dropzone.js** has this in front of it, this is also happening for **d3.min.js**

[image]

My **bootstrap-notify-init.js** has the following added in front

[image]

So it seems random but it looks like parts of string and I have no idea where they could be coming from!

This is what the **fullcalendar-init.js** looks like

[image]